# Adding comma separated items on separate lines to a dict in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7, and using python `dict`s.

I have my output like this:

```
goods: apples, oranges
trunk_names: trunk01, trunk02, trunk03,trunk04,
             trunk05,trunk06, trunk07,trunk08,
             trunk09,trunk10, trunk11,trunk12
```

My code:

```
    d = {}
    for line in output.split("\n"):
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value
```

Expected key and its value:

```
 trunk_names: trunk01, trunk02, trunk03,trunk04,trunk05,trunk06, trunk07,trunk08,trunk09,trunk10, trunk11,trunk12
```

Actual key and values being output:

```
 trunk_names: trunk01, trunk02, trunk03,trunk04,
```

Comment: If your line doesn't have a colon, you just skip it. Why?

Comment: Since you are parsing the file line by line, you miss the second two lines of the values under `trunk_names`. Those lines don't have a colon and your code doesn't do anything to parse them

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = '''
goods: apples, oranges
trunk_names: trunk01, trunk02, trunk03,trunk04,
             trunk05,trunk06, trunk07,trunk08,
             trunk09,trunk10, trunk11,trunk12
'''

d = defaultdict(list)

current_key = None

for line in output.split('\n')[1:]:
    if ":" in line:
        current_key = line.split(':')[0].strip()
        values = line.split(':')[1]
    else:
        values = line

    d[current_key] += [
        value.strip()
        for value in values.split(',')
        if value.strip()
    ]


print(d)
```

gives:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'trunk_names': ['trunk01', 'trunk02', 'trunk03', 'trunk04', 'trunk05', 'trunk06', 'trunk07', 'trunk08', 'trunk09', 'trunk10', 'trunk11', 'trunk12'], 'goods': ['apples', 'oranges']})
```

Answer (score 0):

How stable is your structure, if it is very stable and the data quality is high then your can simplify by testing if the `line.endswith(',')`:

```
In []:
d = {}
f = iter(output.split('\n'))
for line in f:
    key, line = map(str.strip, line.split(':', 1))
    while line.endswith(','):
        line += next(f)
    d[key] = [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]

pprint.pprint(d)

Out[]:
{'goods': ['apples', 'oranges'],
 'trunk_names': ['trunk01',
                 'trunk02',
                 'trunk03',
                 'trunk04',
                 'trunk05',
                 'trunk06',
                 'trunk07',
                 'trunk08',
                 'trunk09',
                 'trunk10',
                 'trunk11',
                 'trunk12']}
```